# Prove if $A$ has $n$ elements then $\mathscr{P_2}(A)$ has $\frac{n(n − 1)}{2}$ elements.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am working on this question

> If $A$ is a set, let $\mathscr{P_2}(A)$ be the set of all subsets of $A$ that have exactly two elements. Prove that for every set A, if $A$ has $n$ elements then $\mathscr{P_2}(A)$ has $\frac{n(n − 1)}{2}$ elements.

prove by induction

**Proof:**

Base case: when $A$ has one element, $\mathscr{P_2}(A)$ two elements. This is true.

Induction case: suppose $A$ has $n$ elements, then $\mathscr{P_2}(A)$ has $\frac{n(n − 1)}{2}$ ; to show if $A$ has $n+1$ elements, then $\mathscr{P_2}(A)$ has $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$.

Then we have: $$ \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{2n}{2}=\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$$

Therefore, if $A$ has $n$ elements, then $\mathscr{P_2}(A)$ has $\frac{n(n − 1)}{2}$ elements. $\small\square$

Does my proof valid? If not, can anyone give me a hit or suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: The sentence "Then we have..." skips a lot of argument. It's the right argument, but you don't say where you got any of those expressions. Also, it is weird that you have $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ on both sides - as if you are proving that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

2 issues:

1. Your base case has an error: if $|A|=1$, then $|\mathscr{P}_2(A)|=0=1\times(1-1)/2$. Perhaps this is your intended meaning but the wording is a bit strange.
2. While the manipulation
   $$
   \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{2n}{2}=\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}
   $$
   is correct, it's not clear what you are trying to say with it. Perhaps you meant something like this:

Suppose $|A|=n+1$ and let $B$ be $A\backslash\{a_0\}$ for some element $a_0$ of $A$. Let's look at the elements of $\mathscr{P}_2(A)$. Either an element is formed from 2 members from $B$ or an element is formed by pairing $a_0$ with a member of $B$. By the induction hypothesis, there are $n(n-1)/2$  formations of the first kind and, because $|B|=n$, there are $n$ formations of the second kind. We conclude:
$$
|\mathscr{P}_2(A)|=|\mathscr{P}_2(B)|+n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\cdot
$$